# Batch TASKLIST to variables

Tags: batch-file, store, taskkill, tasklist

I would like to find if an application is open and get it's PID. For this, I used,

```
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" get ProcessId
```

If there are two, `notepad.exe`s open, it shows 2 PID's. I want to `taskkill` one if 2 are open. How would I approach doing this. How can I check if there are 2 of the same named processes(with specific names) open at a time? Is there a way I can store the `tasklist` in a list?

Comment: How to decide which of the two to kill?

Comment: I wouldn't mind any for now. Later, I can set a custom window title and then close accordingly, but for now I would like any. @zb226

Comment: There's no need to choose between any number of same processes because you only need to kill a single process with a defined window title. That therefore should be your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A I=0
SET PIDS=
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('wmic process where name^="notepad.exe" get ProcessId ^| FINDSTR /v ProcessId ^| FINDSTR /r /v "^$"') DO (
    SET /A I=I+1
    SET PIDS=!PIDS!%%G,
    SET PIDS=!PIDS: =!
)
SET PIDS=!PIDS:~1,-1!
ECHO Found %I% processes
ECHO PIDs: %PIDS%
```

It will output the process count and the PIDs as a comma-separated list. Here's the output if i run it against `chrome.exe`:

```
C:\tmp>q46277950.bat
Found 12 processes
PIDs: 1696,5668,11644,4240,1624,4284,15076,15236,2816,11388,5652,5840
```